# Are questions on reasoning & argumentation on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

For example, I believe that the particular passage from Malcolm Gladwell's Outliers contains faulty reasoning (obviously I might be wrong):

> The striking thing about Ericsson’s study is that he and his
>   colleagues couldn’t find any “naturals,” musicians who floated
>   effortlessly to the top while practicing a fraction of the time their
>   peers did. Nor could they find any “grinds,” people who worked harder
>   than everyone else, yet just didn’t have what it takes to break the
>   top ranks.

This is what is known in economics as an endogeneity problem -- that cause and effect are reversed, and I would use that as a basis to challenge the conclusions made by the author.

Would I be able to ask questions about (faulty) reasoning and argument on this site? Or would it be more appropriate on the language, stats or a domain-specific site?

Comment: Your challenge as presented here is a bit opaque to me - I'm not sure what reasoning there even is in the excerpt. It just reads like two empirical statements to me. But maybe that's just my problem, and in any case, a sufficiently thought-out challenge to an established argument is usually welcome here.

Comment: @commando Ah true. This empirical evidence (in itself questionable) is forwarded in the context of a thesis for which they are not valid arguments (IMHO). I have obviously gone and omitted the context. Regardless, I have my answer.

Comment: This isn't answer the question, but Reddit has many subreddits for this: [r/ChangeMyView](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChangeMyView), [r/ExplainBothSides](https://www.reddit.com/r/ExplainBothSides), [r/NoStupidQuestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions), [r/TrueAskReddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueAskReddit), [r/steelmanning](https://www.reddit.com/r/steelmanning), [r/TheMonkeysPaw](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheMonkeysPaw), [r/TMBR](https://www.reddit.com/r/TMBR) (Test My Belief Reddit)