# Are questions about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

The question [How to disprove a social anxiety fear?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21719/12937) is closed on Psychology SE because it is about the behavior of an individual. However, reading that question I feel that it is fine to call it a question about logic. Therefore, I would like to know if such question on-topic here?

To elaborate, [cognitive therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_therapy) is strongly about challenging misbelief/uncover implicit assumption/identify automatic thought/correct distortion, using logical techniques such as [Socratic questioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning). I think this is in the category of informal logic and applied philosophy.

What do you think?

<sup>Related:

• [Are questions on reasoning & argumentation on-topic here?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/19487)

• [Are question about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on-topic?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2433/12937) on Psychology SE</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good question on any SE has at least the following characteristics:

1. It interests enough members to get a net positive vote of at least 1.
2. It motivates enough members to write at least one acceptable answer.
3. The question does not encourage opinion-based answers.
4. It should take only 24 hours from first asking the question to checking an acceptable answer.

Are people who use this site likely to know anything about cognitive therapy?  When I queried for "cognitive therapy" only 8 items returned. Even for the cognitive-psychology tag there are only 10 questions. And the cognitive-psychology tag has no information in it.  That should be remedied first by writing a tag wiki for this topic.

What does that tell me? It tells me that the people who use this site know little about cognitive therapy or cognitive psychology and, what is worse, they likely have little interest in it.  Even if the question is not closed, it will not get any interesting answers.

However, I would not be too discouraged about that. I have interests that aren't shared by the majority of users on this site and I have created tags for those interests. Slowly I add very, very specific questions to those tagged questions that I am interested in. You may be able to do the same with cognitive therapy.

Look at the goal of participation here as learning about topics one is interested in *with other people*. It is not about finding a hard, cutting-edge question no one can answer. The question needs to involve users. Nothing keeps my interest more than the thought, "Hey! I might be able to answer that!"  Getting those other people involved takes rhetorical skill to draw them in enough to try to answer a question.

So to answer the question: "Are questions about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on topic?"  They can be, but it may be challenging to phrase the questions in such a way that people who don't know what this is won't dismiss it before considering it.